# Running rake task from Windows scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, scheduling

I have a custom Rake file, which I want to run periodically(every day). I am using a Windows machine, and have a .bat file, which basically does

```
cd path/to/applicaion
rake filename
```

I am using the windows scheduler to run the bat file but it aborts, complaining that some gems are missing. However, when I start up a command prompt(using InstantRails.exe), and then run the .bat file from there, it works as expected. I think there is some issue with the PATH, but I am not able to figure out what exactly needs to be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Got it resolved! Needed to add the rails bin folders to the path, and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to this question is at [How can I run a Rake task as a Windows "scheduled task"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020344/how-can-i-run-a-rake-task-as-a-windows-scheduled-task).

There, they point out you can use RAILS_ENV=production (or development, or test) to set the environment you want to rake on.